# Javascript passed array has no length

Tags: javascript

my javascript code stop executing when I try to access the length property from my passed array.

```
var arrParams = getParams(url);
var strRef = getRef(arrParams);

function getRef(pv_arrParams)
{
    portFromCS.postMessage({greeting: 'before .length'});
    portFromCS.postMessage({greeting: pv_arrParams.length}); <- no log
    .
    .
    .
}
```

the array is not null or empty. When I debug its works fine but not otherwise.

edit: here is an example. Its a Firefox addon
https://www.file-upload.net/download-12913625/example.rar.html

so when I debug its not empty or undefined:

[image]

Comment: You're probably having this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: Show `console.log(pv_arrParams);`

Comment: Check its an array or not?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: there is no ajax. when I log the pv_arrParams before I call my getRef-function I get undefined but when I debug its works like a charm. So its very strange for me. just uploaded my code

Comment: You set `url` inside a `.then` block. You may want to take a look at the `ES2015+: Promises with then()` section of the linked question?   The debugger is very likely executing and grabbing the state after the `.then` block has had a chance to run.

Comment: So do I have to work with await here?